# C# using C library with pointer etc

Tags: c#, c, dll, dllexport

I have a .dll without source code.
That library is wrote in C... I have only one .h
An extract of the library is this:

```
typedef enum
{
    SSHD_ERR_NONE = 0,
    SSHD_ERR_INVALID_HANDLE,
    SSHD_ERR_NULL_POINTER,
}sshdErr_t;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned long  Year;            // 
    unsigned long  Month;       // 1...12
    unsigned long  Day;         // 1...31

    unsigned long  Hour;        // 0...23
    unsigned long  Min;         // 0...59
    unsigned long  Sec;         // 0...59
    unsigned long  MilliSec;    // 0...999
} sshdDateTime_t;


    DllExport HANDLE sshdCreate(void);
    DllExport sshdErr_t sshdGetDllVersion(char *dllVersion, unsigned long dllVersionMaxLen);

    DllExport sshdErr_t sshdOpen(HANDLE rh);

I have write this code:



      private const String dllPath = @"D:\work\SSHD.dll";

    [DllImport(dllPath,EntryPoint = "sshdOpen")]
        internal static extern eSSHD_Err Extern_sshdOpen();


        [DllImport(dllPath,EntryPoint = "sshdGetDllVersion")]
        //internal static extern string sshdGetDllVersion();
        internal static extern eSSHD_Err Extern_sshdGetDllVersion(string dllVer , Int32 maxLen );

        [DllImport(dllPath, EntryPoint = "sshdCreate")]
        internal static extern IntPtr Extern_sshdCreate();

    public enum eSSHD_Err {
        SSHD_ERR_NONE = 0,
        SSHD_ERR_INVALID_HANDLE,
        SSHD_ERR_NULL_POINTER,
    }

  public class SSHDDateTime {
    public ulong Year { get; set; }     // 
    public ulong Month { get; set; }    // 1...12
    public ulong Day { get; set; }      // 1...31
    public ulong Hour { get; set; }  // 0...23
    public ulong Min { get; set; }      // 0...59
    public ulong Sec { get; set; }    // 0...59
    public ulong MilliSec { get; set; } // 0...999

    public SSHDDateTime() {
      Year = 0;
      Month = 0;
      Day = 0;
      Hour = 0;
      Min = 0;
      Sec = 0;
      MilliSec = 0;
    }
  }
```

So I use Dll import, convert enum in enum (C#) and struct in class...

When I try to use I have an error...

Now the code for use the library:

```
  IntPtr handle;
  handle = Extern_sshdCreate();
```

this MAYBE work... It means that value of "handle" change.... but I really not know if it work!

when I try to use the other function, in this way:

```
int retProva = (int) (Extern_sshdOpen(handle));
```

or

```
eSSHD_Err retProva = Extern_sshdOpen(handle);
```

I have an error of stack corrupted...

Using the other function is the same results:

```
string dllVer="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
Int32 maxLen = 10;
Extern_sshdGetDllVersion(dllVer,maxLen);
```

I try to use string or String for the dllVer or to use = "         " ...
I try to store the retruned value and not
I try to use Int32, string, ulong for maxLen 
nut all try without result...

the error returned, in Italian, is this:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' : 'Una chiamata
>   alla funzione PInvoke
>   'TestSTSWavetronix!TestSTSWavetronix.FormTestWavetronix::Extern_sshdGetDllVersion'
>   ha sbilanciato lo stack. Questo problema può verificarsi quando la
>   firma PInvoke gestita non corrisponde alla firma di destinazione non
>   gestita. Verificare che la convenzione di chiamata e i parametri della
>   firma PInvoke corrispondano alla firma di destinazione non gestita.'

So I ask:
1. How to use correctly this call?
2. I transform enum C in enum C#, but for return value, how to adapt?
3. similar to previous, how to pass struct C to function, if in C# I have class instead?
4. I have a pointer on C parameter function call... how to manage with him? I suppose that the C code try to modify the string that I pass....

edit:
other try:
- use unsafe in compilation proprierties and before prototype 
- use "enum : int"  on definition of enum

edit 2:
********************** WORKING SOLUTION *************

```
  public enum eSSHD_Err {
    SSHD_ERR_NONE = 0,
    SSHD_ERR_INVALID_HANDLE,
    SSHD_ERR_NULL_POINTER,
}
    [DllImport(dllPath,EntryPoint = "sshdGetDllVersion",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    unsafe internal static extern eSSHD_Err Extern_sshdGetDllVersion(ref char dllVer,Int32 maxLen);
char[] dllVer = new char[250];
Int32 maxLen = 250;
retErrGetDllVer = Extern_sshdGetDllVersion(ref dllVer[0],maxLen);
```

Thanks to all

Massimiliano

Comment: Like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419415/c-sharp-call-c-dll-passing-pointer-to-pointer-argument Have you tried tu put unsafe before internal static extern and in DllImport: CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl?

Comment: The stack error usually means the return variable size from calling function doesn't match the parent return size.  So specify the size in the enumeration : public enum eSSHD_Err : int //or the size from the c++ library.

Comment: Hi, I  try to compile with unsafe (build option AND before the prototype)
I try to use CallingConvention in Cdec, now I try to keep in my code....

@jdweng I have try now in this way:

typedef enum : int
{
 SSHD_ERR_NONE = 0,
 SSHD_ERR_INVALID_HANDLE,
 SSHD_ERR_NULL_POINTER,
}

but without success...
The error remain the same.

I try to call the fnction without expecting return..

So both: eSSHD_Err retProva = Extern_sshdOpen(handle); and Extern_sshdOpen(handle);

Comment: I don't think call will work with unsafe code.  Never tried it.

Comment: Can you get the value of handle after calling Extern_sshdCreate(); ?

Comment: Hi, yes Handle value is this (I don't know if it is valid or not):
Before: 0x00000000   (all zero)   
After:    0x077d2ac0

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `StructLayoutAttribute` to your managed struct declaration. The C# compiler is permitted to re-order
struct members for efficiency if it deems it beneficial, so this will prevent that. Since `long` is *usually* a 32-bit integer in C, I have changed the field types to `uint`.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class SSHDDateTime {
  public uint Year { get; set; }     // 
  public uint Month { get; set; }    // 1...12
  public uint Day { get; set; }      // 1...31
  public uint Hour { get; set; }  // 0...23
  public uint Min { get; set; }      // 0...59
  public uint Sec { get; set; }    // 0...59
  public uint MilliSec { get; set; } // 0...999

  public SSHDDateTime() {
    Year = 0;
    Month = 0;
    Day = 0;
    Hour = 0;
    Min = 0;
    Sec = 0;
    MilliSec = 0;
  }
}
```

Next, pass a `StringBuilder` to the `Extern_sshdGetDllVersion` function. This function is expecting a character
buffer, and the managed equivalent of a character buffer is a `StringBuilder`. The PInvoke marshaler has detailed
knowledge of the `StringBuilder` class to handle interop marshaling of strings. You can add the `MarshalAsAttribute` as a hint to the marshaler that you are dealing with ANSI strings in the native library. Also, the default calling convention for the `DllImportAttribute` is `StdCall`, which is *likely* not what you want here. This revised signature specifies the `Cdecl` calling convention, which is the standard convention for C programs. If your C library is in fact compiled to use `StdCall`, then you can take that part out, but I think that is the source of your stack corruption.

```
    [DllImport(dllPath, EntryPoint = "sshdGetDllVersion", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern eSSHD_Err Extern_sshdGetDllVersion([MarshlAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]StringBuilder dllVer , Int32 maxLen );
```

The PInvoke signatures for the other functions would be as follows:

```
[DllImport(dllPath, EntryPoint = "sshdOpen", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl))]
internal static extern eSSHD_Err Extern_sshdOpen();

[DllImport(dllPath, EntryPoint = "sshdCreate", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl))]
internal static extern IntPtr Extern_sshdCreate();
```

Comment: Hi to all!
Now work! I use the calling convention and the ref instead char *...
Now I write the working code